# SQL Server - Clustered index design for dictionary

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, clustered-index

Would like some advice from this. I got a table where I want to keep track of an object and a list of keys related to the object. Example:

```
OBJECTID   ITEMTYPE   ITEMKEY
--------   --------   -------
1          1          THE
1          1          BROWN
1          2          APPLE
1          3          ORANGE
2          2          WINDOW
```

Both OBJECTID and ITEMKEY have high selectivity (i.e. the OBJECTID and ITEMKEY are very varied). My access are two ways:

- By OBJECTID: Each time an object changes, the list of key changes so a key is needed based on OBJECTID. Changes happen frequently.
- By ITEMKEY: This is for keyword searching and also happens frequently.

So I probably need two keys, and choose one for clustered index (the one that is more frequently accessed, or where I want the speed to be, for now lets assume i will prioritize OBJECTID for clustered). What I am confused about is how I should design it.

My questions is, which is better:

a) A Clustered index of (OBJECTID,ITEMTYPE,ITEMKEY), and then an index of (ITEMKEY). My concern is that since a clustered index is so big (2 ints, 1 string) the index will be big, because all index items got to point back to the clustered key.

b) Create a new column with a running identity DIRECTORYID (integer) as primary key and clustered index, and declare two index for (OBJECTID,ITEMTYPE,ITEMKEY) and just (ITEMKEY). This will minimize index space but have higher lookup costs.

c) A Clustered index of (OBJECTID,ITEMTYPE,ITEMKEY), and a materialized view of (ITEMKEY,ITEMTYPE,OBJECTID) on it. My logic is that this is avoids a key lookup and will still be just as big as the index with a lookup in a), at cost of higher overhead.

d) Err...maybe there is a better way given the requirements?

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: Why do you think you need to cluster on `(OBJECTID,ITEMTYPE,ITEMKEY)` instead of `(OBJECTID)` only?

Comment: If you're trying to build a high-performance keyword search in SQL Server, you should consider full-text searching: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx

Comment: @Lucero: clustering key must be unique - and ObjectId is not. In this case, SQL Server will add a four-byte uniqueifier to your index entries - you can avoid that by choosing a truly unique column (INT IDENTITY) for your clustering key.

Comment: @marc_s: given the choice of columns in this question I'd suppose that the implicitly generated unique integer column should be better than most other combinations. Of course if there is a good match for clustering on an unique index one should use it, but here there isn't IMHO.

Comment: @Lucero: Thanks for your comments, I get what you are saying, but if SQL is going to add it anyway, I might as well add my own identity/pk/clusterkey e.g. (OBJECTID,DIRECTORYID) so that I can use it as a single unique key if I ever need to (since the hidden SQL one is inaccessible). But I agree with you that this will be better than using (OBJECTID,iTEMTYPE,ITEMKEY) if clustering by OBJECTID is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ever possible, try to keep your clustered key as small as possible, since it will be also added to all non-clustered indices on your table.

Therefore, I would use an INT if ever possible, or possibly a combination of two INT - but certainly never a `VARCHAR` column - especially if that column is potentially wide (> 10 chars) and is bound to change.

So of the options you present, I personally would choose b) - why??

Adding a surrogate `DirectoryID` will satisfy all crucial criteria for a clustering key:

- small
- stable
- unique
- ever-increasing

and your other non-clustered indices will be minimally impacted.

See Kimberly Tripp's [outstanding blog post](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx) on the main criteria for choosing a good clustering key on your SQL Server tables - very useful and enlightening!

To satisfy your query requirements, I would add two non-clustered indices, one on `ObjectID` (possibly including other columns frequently needed), and another on `ItemKey` to search by keyname.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the post, it's enlightening (it may seem more intuitive to try to cluster by what is most often used, but from the article, seems like given real world situations, there are other overheads involved that makes it better to follow these rules on the cluster key!)

Comment: marc_s: I got a question for your opinion: would it make sense to use (OBJECTID,DirectoryID) as the cluster-key? This would at least make it cluster by one criteria, while keeping the cluster key smallish (but would lose the inserting always at end of table property). Is it worth it, would you ever do this in your design?

Comment: @andrwo: if DirectoryID would be an INT IDENTITY column, then I would cluster on only this single INT - no point in adding a second INT to the clustering index, really - or why would you want to do this??

Comment: @marc_s: Purely for performance reasons, since the table is huge, figured that it will shortcut the bookmark lookup while accessing by OBJECTID (since if clustered by (DirectoryID) SQL server still need to lookup each item to change it). Actually there are argument both ways depending on what I want to maximize (cluster index fragmentation, space, update performance), but I am just polling generally opinion to see if DB designers typically do this kind of thing, or they usually try their best to stick to the increasing-integer-identity-cluster rule. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @andrwo: if you want to reduce bookmark lookups, create a non-clustered index on the columns you want to search on, and INCLUDE any additional columns that make sense. I wouldn't "pollute" the clustered index which is so crucial to have good performance on with something unless absolutely necessary....

Comment: @marc_s: Ok got you, thank you for your guidance and opinions on this.