# Leaderboard design using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, azure-sql-database

I am building a leaderboard for some of my online games. Here is what I need to do with the data:

- Get rank of a player for a given game across multiple time frame (today, last week, all time, etc.)
- Get paginated ranking (e.g. top score for last 24 hrs., get players between rank 25 and 50, get rank or a single user)

I defined with the following table definition and index and I have a couple of questions.

**Considering my scenarios, do I have a good primary key?** The reason why I have a clustered key across gameId, playerName and score is simply because I want to make sure that all data for a given game is in the same area and that score is already sorted. Most of the time I will display the data is descending order of score (+ updatedDateTime for ties) for a given gameId. Is this a right strategy? In other words, I want to make sure that I can run my queries to get the rank of my players as fast as possible.

```
CREATE TABLE score (
    [gameId]            [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [playerName]        [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [score]             [int] NOT NULL,
    [createdDateTime]   [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
    [updatedDateTime]   [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([gameId] ASC, [playerName] ASC, [score] DESC, [updatedDateTime] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Score_Idx] ON score ([gameId] ASC, [score] DESC, [updatedDateTime] ASC) INCLUDE ([playerName])
```

Below is the first iteration of the query I will be using to get the rank of my players. However, I am a bit disappointed by the execution plan (see below). **Why does SQL need to sort?** The additional sort seem to come from the RANK function. But isn’t my data already sorted in descending order (based on the clustered key of the score table)? I am also wondering if I should normalize a bit more my table and move out the PlayerName column in a Player table. I originally decided to keep everything in the same table to minimize the number of joins.

```
DECLARE @GameId AS INT = 0
DECLARE @From AS DATETIME2(3) = '2013-10-01'

SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Score DESC), s.PlayerName, s.Score, s.CountryCode, s.updatedDateTime
FROM [mrgleaderboard].[score] s
WHERE s.GameId = @GameId 
  AND (s.UpdatedDateTime >= @From OR @From IS NULL)
```

[image]

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: when designing the primary key, keep in mind that you may be using up a lot of resources when inserting new values.
as for the sorting: your primary key is first sorted by game and player and then by score. basically you are sorting the player's score for each game, which is (if you are only interested in the player's highest score per game) very pointless. in your query however you are ranking (i.e. sorting) the scores across all players for a game.

Comment: Hello @BrettSchneider. I don't have any data to back this up, but I am under the impression that inserting/updating a score will happen less often then querying for the rank of the player or getting the list of top players. That's why I was trying to have a clustered key which include the player score. That way, the data would be almost sorted.

Comment: the dense_rank will imho require an index `[gameid], [score], [updatedtime]` to work without sorting. what is your motivation to cluster by `[playername]` after `[gameid]`? if you are querying the rank of a player across games, this will not help as you want to rank the player by score.

Comment: @Martin I updated my post, please check

Comment: If I've understood this correctly, surely the primary key should be set to `GameId` and `PlayerName` as I'm guessing you are having unique names. Given that the items are being updated regularly with the score and updated date these should not be used, I'm guessing the `GameId` and `PlayerName` are the only constants and ultimately would be unique.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Updated]

**Primary key is not good**

You have a unique entity that is [GameID] + [PlayerName]. And composite clustered Index > 120 bytes  with nvarchar. Look for the answer by @marc_s in the related topic [SQL Server - Clustered index design for dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849068/sql-server-clustered-index-design-for-dictionary?rq=1)

**Your table schema does not match of your requirements to time periods**

Ex.: I earned 300 score on Wednesday and this score stored on leaderboard. Next day I earned 250 score, but it will not record on leaderboard and you don't get results if I run a query to Tuesday leaderboard

For complete information you can get from a historical table games played score but it can be very expensive

```
CREATE TABLE GameLog (
  [id]                int NOT NULL IDENTITY
                      CONSTRAINT [PK_GameLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  [gameId]            smallint NOT NULL,
  [playerId]          int NOT NULL,
  [score]             int NOT NULL,
  [createdDateTime]   datetime2(3) NOT NULL)
```

Here are solutions to accelerate it related with the aggregation:

- Indexed view on historical table (see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19980350/911976) by @Twinkles).

You need 3 indexed view for the 3 time periods. Potentially huge size of historical tables and 3 indexed view. Unable to remove the "old" periods of the table. Performance issue to save score.

- Asynchronous leaderboard

Scores saved in the historical table. SQL job/"Worker" (or several) according to schedule (1 per minute?) sorts historical table and populates the leaderboards table (3 tables for 3 time period or one table with time period key) with the precalculated rank of a user. This table also can be denormalized (have score, datetime, PlayerName and ...). Pros: Fast reading (without sorting), fast save score, any time periods, flexible logic and flexible schedules. Cons: The user has finished the game but did not found immediately himself on the leaderboard

- Preaggregated leaderboard

During recording the results of the game session do pre-treatment. In your case something like `UPDATE [Leaderboard] SET score = @CurrentScore WHERE @CurrentScore > MAX (score) AND ...` for the player / game id but you did it only for "All time" leaderboard. The scheme might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Leaderboard] (
    [id]                int NOT NULL IDENTITY
                             CONSTRAINT [PK_Leaderboard] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [gameId]            smallint NOT NULL,
    [playerId]          int NOT NULL,
    [timePeriod]        tinyint NOT NULL,   -- 0 -all time, 1-monthly, 2 -weekly, 3 -daily
    [timePeriodFrom]    date NOT NULL,  -- '1900-01-01' for all time, '2013-11-01' for monthly, etc.
    [score]             int NOT NULL,
    [createdDateTime]   datetime2(3) NOT NULL
    )
```

```
playerId    timePeriod  timePeriodFrom  Score
----------------------------------------------
1           0           1900-01-01      300  
...
1           1           2013-10-01      150
1           1           2013-11-01      300
...
1           2           2013-10-07      150
1           2           2013-11-18      300
...
1           3           2013-11-19      300
1           3           2013-11-20      250
...
```

So, you have to update all 3 score for all time period. Also as you can see leaderboard will contain "old" periods, such as monthly of October. Maybe you have to delete it if you do not need this statistics. Pros: Does not need a historical table. Cons: Complicated procedure for storing the result. Need maintenance of leaderboard. Query requires sorting and JOIN

```
CREATE TABLE [Player] (
    [id]    int NOT NULL IDENTITY CONSTRAINT [PK_Player] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [playerName]        nvarchar(50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [UQ_Player_playerName] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED)

CREATE TABLE [Leaderboard] (
    [id]                int NOT NULL IDENTITY CONSTRAINT [PK_Leaderboard] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [gameId]            smallint NOT NULL,
    [playerId]          int NOT NULL,
    [timePeriod]        tinyint NOT NULL,   -- 0 -all time, 1-monthly, 2 -weekly, 3 -daily
    [timePeriodFrom]    date NOT NULL,  -- '1900-01-01' for all time, '2013-11-01' for monthly, etc.
    [score]             int NOT NULL,
    [createdDateTime]   datetime2(3) 
)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_Leaderboard_gameId_playerId_timePeriod_timePeriodFrom] ON [Leaderboard] ([gameId] ASC, [playerId] ASC, [timePeriod]  ASC,  [timePeriodFrom] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Leaderboard_gameId_timePeriod_timePeriodFrom_Score] ON [Leaderboard] ([gameId] ASC, [timePeriod]  ASC,  [timePeriodFrom] ASC, [score] ASC)
GO

-- Generate test data
-- Generate 500K unique players
;WITH digits (d) AS (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION
   SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0)

INSERT INTO Player (playerName)
SELECT TOP (500000) LEFT(CAST(NEWID() as nvarchar(50)), 20 + (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) & 15)) as Name
FROM   digits CROSS JOIN digits ii CROSS  JOIN digits iii CROSS  JOIN digits iv CROSS  JOIN digits v CROSS  JOIN digits vi

-- Random score 500K players * 4 games = 2M rows
INSERT INTO [Leaderboard] (
    [gameId],[playerId],[timePeriod],[timePeriodFrom],[score],[createdDateTime])
SELECT  GameID, Player.id,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) & 3 as [timePeriod], DATEADD(MILLISECOND, CHECKSUM(NEWID()),GETDATE()) as Updated, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) & 65535 as score
    , DATEADD(MILLISECOND, CHECKSUM(NEWID()),GETDATE()) as Created
FROM (  SELECT 1 as GameID  UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4) as Game
    CROSS JOIN Player
ORDER BY NEWID()
UPDATE [Leaderboard] SET [timePeriodFrom]='19000101' WHERE [timePeriod] = 0
GO

DECLARE @From date = '19000101'--'20131108'
    ,@GameID int = 3
    ,@timePeriod tinyint = 0

-- Get paginated ranking 
;With Lb as (
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Score DESC) as Rnk
    ,Score, createdDateTime, playerId
FROM [Leaderboard]
WHERE GameId = @GameId
  AND [timePeriod] = @timePeriod
  AND [timePeriodFrom] = @From)

SELECT lb.rnk,lb.Score, lb.createdDateTime, lb.playerId, Player.playerName
FROM Lb INNER JOIN Player ON lb.playerId = Player.id
ORDER BY rnk OFFSET 75 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY;

-- Get rank of a player for a given game 
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT rnk.score) 
        FROM [Leaderboard] as rnk 
        WHERE rnk.GameId = @GameId 
            AND rnk.[timePeriod] = @timePeriod
            AND rnk.[timePeriodFrom] = @From
            AND rnk.score >= [Leaderboard].score) as rnk
    ,[Leaderboard].Score, [Leaderboard].createdDateTime, [Leaderboard].playerId, Player.playerName
FROM [Leaderboard]  INNER JOIN Player ON [Leaderboard].playerId = Player.id
where [Leaderboard].GameId = @GameId
    AND [Leaderboard].[timePeriod] = @timePeriod
    AND [Leaderboard].[timePeriodFrom] = @From
    and Player.playerName = N'785DDBBB-3000-4730-B'
GO
```

This is only an example for the presentation of ideas. It can be optimized. For example, combining columns GameID, TimePeriod, TimePeriodDate to one column through the dictionary table. The effectiveness of the index will be higher.

P.S. Sorry for my English. Feel free to fix grammatical or spelling errors

Comment: I understand your point of view, but now all my queries will require a join, which is not very good for performance. I need this leaderboard to be fast with >500,000 scores.

Comment: @Martin I have experience leaderboards for social games. And looking at your description I have done similar functionality. In the case of nvarchar(50) the size of the index will be 5 times larger, which means you'll get 5 times more load on the I/O. About JOIN - In most cases, the name of the player need only a small number of already sorted data - for ex. TOP 100. And join by primary key is quite cheap operation. Please describe in detail one of the query and may be able to find the optimal solution.

Comment: You have one of the query I am trying to do in the question.

Comment: If a player can have multiple scores for a game the index has to be adjusted to `CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_Score_gameId_playerId] ON score ([gameId] ASC, [playerId] ASC, [createdDateTime] ASC)`

Comment: @Twinkles I saw a column [createdDateTime] and [UpdatedDateTime] and realized that the table stores only a maximum score in this game for the player. And the ALL gaming sessions stored in a separate historical table that is may be much larger and even can be backuped/truncated time to time. In my opinion it will provide better performance.

Comment: And the UpdateDatetime is used to determine which score came first, I would keep it as a DateTime.

Comment: @Twinkles If this is important to you then of course you should keep it as DateTime. But looks like @Martin don't care about it. `SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Score DESC), ... FROM ... WHERE .. UpdatedDateTime >= @From`.

Comment: @Twinkles A player can have a single score for a given game. We only car about the top score.

Answer (score 4):

You could look into [indexed views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx) to create scoreboards for common time ranges (today, this week/month/year, all-time).

Comment: In some cases, this is a good solution, but we need to look at the  INSERT/UPDATE performance. Depends on the number of requests to read the leaderboard and the number of add/updates scores.

Comment: Quote from your link: "Applications that benefit from the implementation of indexed views include:
•Decision support workloads.
•Data marts.
•Data warehouses.
•Online analytical processing (OLAP) stores and sources.
•Data mining workloads.
On the contrary, online transaction processing (OLTP) systems with many writes, or database applications with frequent updates, may not be able to take advantage of indexed views because of the increased maintenance cost associated with updating both the view and underlying base tables."

Answer (score 2):

to get the rank of a player for a given game across multiple timeframes, you will select the game and rank (i.e. sort) by score over a multiple timeframes. for this, your nonclustered index could be changed like this since this is the way your select seems to query.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Score_Idx] 
ON score ([gameId] ASC, [updatedDateTime] ASC, [score] DESC) 
INCLUDE ([playerName])
```

for the paginated ranking:

for the 24h-top score i guess you will want all the top scores of a single user across all games within the last 24h. for this you will be querying `[playername], [updateddatetime]` with `[gameid]`.

for the players between rank 25-50, i assume you are talking about a single game and have a long ranking that you can page through. the query will then be based upon `[gameid], [score]` and a little on `[updateddatetime]` for the ties.

the single-user ranks, probably for each game, is a little more difficult. you will need to query the leaderboards for all games in order to get the player's rank in them and then filter on the player. you will need `[gameid], [score], [updateddatetime]` and then filter by player.

concluding all this, i propose you keep your nonclustered index and change the primary key to:

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([gameId] ASC, [score] DESC, [updatedDateTime] ASC)
```

for the 24h-top score i think this might help:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [player_Idx] 
ON score ([playerName] ASC) 
INCLUDE ([gameId], [score])
```

the dense_rank query sorts because it selects `[gameId], [updatedDateTime], [score]`. see my comment on the nonclustered index above.

i would also think twice about including the `[updatedDateTime]` in your queries and subsequently in your indexes. maybe sometmes two players get the same rank, why not? `[updatedDateTime]` will let your index swell up significantly.

also you might think about partitioning tables by `[gameid]`.

Answer (score 1):

As a bit of a sidetrack:

Ask yourself how accurate and how up to date do the scores in the leaderboard actually need to be?

As a player I don't care if I'm number 142134 in the world or number 142133. I do care if I beat my friends' exact score (but then I only need my score compared to a couple of other scores) and I want to know that my new highscore sends me from somewhere around 142000 to somewhere around 90000. (Yay!)

So if you want really fast leaderboards, you do not actually need all data to be up to date. You could daily or hourly compute a static sorted copy of the leaderboard and when showing player X's score, show at what rank it'd fit in the static copy.

When comparing to friends, last minute updates do matter, but you're dealing with only a couple hundred scores, so you can look up their actual scores in the up to date leaderboards.

Oh, and I care about the top 10 of course. Consider them my "friends" merely based on the fact that they scored so well, and show these values up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Your clustered index is composite so it means that order is defined by more than one column. You request `ORDER BY Score` which is the 2nd column in the clustered index. For that reason, entries in the index are not necessarily in the order of `Score`, e.g. entries

```
1, 2, some date
2, 1, some other date
```

If you select just `Score`, the order will be

```
2
1
```

which needs to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

i would not put the "score" column into the clustered index because it will probably change all the time ... and updates on a column that's part of the clustered index will be expensive